# How to configure ALE to enable autoformatting with elm-format?

Tags: plugin-ale

I'm trying to enable autoformatting of Elm code (I guess the problem would be the same for any language). In Elm the `elm-format` program can normally used to format the code.

I see that there's an option in ALE to set the path of `elm-format` so I guess `elm-format` is supported by ALE. However I have no idea how to activate the option of autoformatting.

I can only see an option to set the path of [`elm-format`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/8768a309b8ef1c2e819dcb6f4630f73acab59792/doc/ale-elm.txt#L6), but I already have `elm-format` in the default path.

How do I enable the autoformatting ? Or maybe there's a key I have to type so that the code gets formatted? What key is it?

Comment: Have you read [the README](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#2ii-fixing)?

Comment: I had skimmed through it and had searched for something about my problem, but having no idea this feature was called "fixing" (I thought it would be called formatting or autoformatting), I had missed that section entirely. Thanks for poiting me to the right paragraph. It's working now. What I was missing was the `let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1`

Comment: If you want to add an answer to the topic, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable the feature of automatically formatting on save. This can be done by using `:h autocmd`, or with the global variable `ale` provides which enables it. The latter is much simpler and thus preferable.

```
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```